# How to ActiveRecord Query off of specific association when there are two associations with the same model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So lets say I have a Basketball model.

```
class Basketball < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class: User
  belongs_to :last_played_with, class: User
end
```

Now lets say I want to get my basketballs from the database, in order of the last_played_with's name column. Or the owner's. How would I specify which one I'm trying to order by, here, in the query? Would this require raw SQL?

Comment: Are owner and last_playes_with an User class or something? What is your schema.rb?

Comment: Yes, both come from that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

```
Basketball.joins(:owner).order("owners.name")
```

Comment: Rails then complains about how there is no table named "owners".